# how to get rid of NetBeans java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, netbeans

The code:

```
package epshell;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('hej');
    }
}
```

> The error:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\**;5:A59 
>   57=8:>2**\.netbeans\6.9\ant\nblib\org-netbeans-modules-mobility-project.jar (The filename, directory name, or
>   volume label syntax is incorrect)

My username is in russian, how can i fix the error?

Comment: Simply move the project somewhere else.

Comment: The problem isn't with the project folder (yet), but with some of netbeans files (org-netbeans-modules-mobility-project.jar)

Comment: Why do you have such a weird username?

Comment: ;5:A59 57=8:>2 is not my username ) there is a problem with incorrect localization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the file `netbeans.conf` in `etc` folder. If you have x86 OS, it is in

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9.1\etc\netbeans.conf
```

For x64 OS, it is in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 6.9.1\etc\netbeans.conf
```

On the second line, Netbeans sets the default user home to something like:

```
netbeans_default_userdir="${HOME}/.netbeans/6.9"
```

Change it to somthing like:

```
netbeans_default_userdir="C:/Users/yoz1k/.netbeans/6.9"
```

However, if the machine is shared between many users, you should try to fix the `HOME` variable. Otherwise all user will end up using the same netbeans setting/data.

**Update**

If your username is in Russian, try to move `.netbeans` folder to some other path, e.g. `C:\.netbeans` and point the `netbeans_default_userdir` to there.

**Useful info**

If you update your Java SDK, you can change the porperty `netbeans_jdkhome` in `netbeans.conf` to you new JDK location without having to reinstall Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Start NetBeans with the `--userdir <path>` parameter where `<path>` is an alternative user directory (without any special characters).

More info: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir